# Extremely Cheap Geeky Code System

Tags: microcontroller, rfid

I'm hoping to create a really geeky 'capture-the-flag'-style checkpoint event. The goal is as follows:

1. Team A goes to Checkpoint 1 and, using some kind of device, scans a chip left at Checkpoint 1 or some code on a piece of paper to spit out a code.
2. Team B, at the same checkpoint (Checkpoint 1) will get a code unique to that team
3. Team A at Checkpoint 2 gets a unique code once again.

I think the idea is somewhat conveyed here. The idea is that I have a master sheet of all the Team-Checkpoint code combinations but, to the teams, everything is random and can't be guessed.

An issue is that each 'device' for a team, to be economical, will have to be around $15-$20, which is incredibly restrictive, obviously. My original idea was to have an RFID tag at each checkpoint and build an RFID reader with an LCD screen that modified the RFID tag based on some team-specific thing, but I couldn't find an economic way to do this.

The goal is to build something cool and geeky so any neat ideas are appreciated, I guess there's no "correct" answer, but the $15 is restrictive...

Any ideas? Thank you very much!

Comment: how about a notepad and a pencil?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think your description is far from clear, but I think I get the picture.

My first Idea would be to use the mobile-phone-with-camera that every child seems to have nowadays to scan a barcode or something similar. You'll have to write the app(s) and print some barcodes, but otherwise 0 hardware cost.

My second idea would be using infrared. If you can implement the detection in the flags you could use existing IR remotes (maybe with all but one button disabled) for the players.